# Springboot can't read values from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following problem:
I've wanted to read some values (the price of products) from `.properties` file.

However I'm trying, It's always getting `0.00` as a value.

This is my service bean, which in I want to create a product list:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "product-service")
public class ProductService {

    private double first;
    private double second;
    private double third;

    public double getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(double first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public double getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(double second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    public double getThird() {
        return third;
    }

    public void setThird(double third) {
        this.third = third;
    }

    private List<ProductDTO> productList = Arrays.asList(
            new ProductDTO(1, "Tomb Raider", first),
            new ProductDTO(2, "10000 rp to lol", second),
            new ProductDTO(3, "2k valorant points", third)
    );

    public List<ProductDTO> findAllProducts() {
        return productList;
    }
}
```

And this is the property file:

```
product-service.first = 225.00
product-service.second = 320.50
product-service.third = 150.99
```

Comment: You may need either to add `@Configuration` annotation to `ProductService` class or enable it before application run with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation. Also I would move the property-related part out of `@Service` into separate `POJO`.

Comment: @barti_ddu I've tried adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties` and move reading part to other `bean` but it didn't work. I'd like to do it in the same service than making other bean or `POJO` fot that

Comment: @barti_ddu `@Configuration` works like `@Service` in order to create a spring bean. So this is not the cause of the error. Of course the best practice would not be the `@Service` but this is not why the properties are not loaded. Fixing what I describe in my answer should fix the issue

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos: can't believe I've missed that, kudos to You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you use the `prefix = "product-service"`

you should declare your class fields as following.

```
    private double first;
    private double second;
    private double third;
```

You should also update getters and setters.

You also have another error in your code as well

```
private List<ProductDTO> productList = Arrays.asList(
            new ProductDTO(1,"Tomb Raider",first),
            new ProductDTO(2,"10000 rp to lol",second),
            new ProductDTO(3,"2k valorant points",third)
    );
```

This field is initialized when your class is initialized. But Spring initializes your bean with a proxy. So when the class is initialized your `productList` will have `0` values for `first`, `second`,`third`.

If you wish this to work you should replace

```
public List<ProductDTO> findAllProducts() {
        return productList;
    }
```

with

```
public List<ProductDTO> findAllProducts() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new ProductDTO(1,"Tomb Raider",first),
                new ProductDTO(2,"10000 rp to lol",second),
                new ProductDTO(3,"2k valorant points",third)
        );
    }
```

Comment: I've done like u said but it didn't work actually. I'm still getting 0.0 in all doubles

Comment: @Marin8: The only missing thing that I can think of: You don't have ___getters___...

Comment: @barti_ddu added them right now and it's still not working

Comment: @barti_ddu I've editet code in post, you can look around.

Comment: @Marin8 LOL your properties are `product-serive` not `product-service`. Update accordingly and it is fixed!

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos xD that's fact, updated it and updated also a post but it's still not working:(

Comment: @Marin8 your property still is `product-serive.first = 225.00` instead of `product-service.first = 225.00`

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I've updatet it in post rn, it's `product-service.first = 225.00` actually

Comment: @Marin8: Can You temporarily change the `@Service` annotation into `@Configuration`, `@Autowire` the `ProductService` instance anywhere and check its `getFirst()` value?

Comment: @Marin8 I found another error you had as well, check the updated answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos
https://github.com/MateuszBednarczyk/NextProject
here is link to these codes

Comment: @Marin8 please let's not overcomplicate this issue. Check the updated answer and it should be enough to work!

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos ok, it's working rn. Thank you so much! I've spent bout 2.5 hours working on it XD

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix your configuration properties with the service layer.

You have a few ways:

- create a separate configuration class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("product-service")
public class ProductProperties {
    private Double first;
    private Double second;
    private Double third;
    // getters & setters
}
```

And use it directly at your service class:

```
class ProductService {
    private ProductProperties properties;

    // use at code: properties.getFirst()
}
```

depending on your Spring Boot version you may need `@EnableConfigurationProperties({ProductProperties.class})` under any class marked with `@Configuration`

- use `@Value`:

```
class ProductService {
    @Value("${product-service.first}")
    private double first;
    //...
}
```

You should set to your main class:

Useful links:

- [Guide to @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)
- [Quick Guide to Spring @Value](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Comment: It's still reading like 0.

Comment: @catch23 `@Service` would allow the properties to be configured in the spring bean. This annotation to enableConfigruation is not the solution and not the cause of the error

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos updated the answer

Comment: @catch23 The answer still though is not facing the cause of the error OP faced. Check my answer and you will see the other problems in the code that was the cause of problem OP faced for this question

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos now I see the main root of the problem. You were right.